# how to add data ware house project in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio

how to add data ware house project in VS2015 .

Questions:

Need to add any SSDT tools? .
Using SSDT means how will add the project.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to download SSDT tools for VS. When you start to install, make sure to choose the option as "new install", do not to choose "Add it to existing environment"

after you install SSDT, you would be able to open any SSIS/SSRS project as well as create new SSIS/SSRS project.